# React Router 4 - Difficulty with programmatically navigating to new view

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Using react and react-router 4 I'm trying to send a user from the login view to another view after logging in. I've seen a few other questions about this, but none of the solutions, including using history or context have worked for me.

```
const {
  Redirect,
  HashRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} = ReactRouterDOM

const App = () =>  {

  const loginToServer = () => {
  // how do I redirect user to the home route?

  };

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>Some App</h2>

        <HashRouter>
          <div>
            <Link to="/login" exact activeClassName="active">Login </Link><br/>
            <Link to="/home" activeClassName="active">Home </Link><br/>
            <hr/>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login"
                render={ () => <Login loginToServer = { loginToServer } /> }/>
              <Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent} />
              <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/login"/>)}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  };

const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Login Page</h4>
      <p>(pretend button is a submit button for a successful login)</p>
      <button onClick= { props.loginToServer }> login </button>
    </div>
  )}

const HomeComponent = () => <h4>Home page</h4>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The above code is in a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/portland_dan/pen/oGOBwb). Hoping someone can show me the simplest way to implement this. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you alternatives because in real life application you will redirect from other components than your root `App`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the router `history` object to handle redirection. In your case, the component `App` includes the router so you will have to retrieve `history` using `ref`.

```
const App = () =>  {

  let router;

  const loginToServer = () => {
    router.history.push('/home');
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Some App</h2>

      <HashRouter ref={r => router = r}>
        {/* ... */}
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can also do the redirection from your `Login` component

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
//                              ^^^^^
//                   the router will be given as prop to Login 

const Login = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    // ...
      <button onClick={() => history.push('/home')}> login </button>
    // ...
  )
}
```

If you want to redirect from a sub component (not directly attached to a route) you can use the `withRouter` high order component to inject the router.

```
const { withRouter } = ReactRouterDOM;

const SubComponent = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <div onClick={() => history.push('/somewhere')} />
));
```

Comment: Thanks Freez. Any chance you could also show how this would work with App as a stateful, class-based component? Should have written it that way in my code for the question to begin with. With App as a class instead of function, I can't figure out how to access the history object where I need it. And have to say, React-Router 4 is pretty frustrating for me :-(

Comment: If your app is a class, use `this` to store your router ref. 
`<HashRouter ref={r => this.router = r}>`, 
then you can use it in any class function calling `this.router.history.push(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to make sure the method that will handle the redirect has access to the `history` object that is passed on as a prop to any component that is directly `Route`'d to.

Looking at you code, you should move the `loginToServer` function to your `Login` component because, well, why should it ever be called from anywhere else anyway?

Then in your `Login.js` file:

```
loginToServer() {
  ...handle actual login logic here...
  // if successful
  this.props.history.push('/home');
}
```

Edit: You'll have to turn your `Login` component from a functional component to a class.

Comment: I took out a bunch of logic from the relevant files to put up here and on codepen. Still new to react and doing this without redux, so in my login component (which is stateful in my real app) there's validation logic before passing it to the parent component where I have an axios post function communicate with and retrieve a JWT and user info from my server. Not sure if this is best way to do it.